# Beginner EmberJS : Relationship with ManyArray not working

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, server

I write to ask you why can't I get my relational datas in my object.

I explain :

I created two model objects : a user and an institution. The relationship between both is Many To Many.

On the server (actually an embedded stub on /server before switching to a rails server currently in development), the relationship is the same. My server sends datas respecting the JSON API convention. By the way, the Adapter I use in the app extends JSONAPIAdapter.

All datas are correctly filled in : I can fill my user model properly when I call datas through the "find" method from the store in the service, everything's ok :

`this.get('store').find('user', id);`

The user is well returned and I can check out my datas in the app.

But the user also owns an array of "institutions" and this one looks empty. I can't parse it, and user.institutions.length returns "0". However, when I check out the Ember Inspector, I can see the institution in "datas", so the request seems to be functional...

I set async : true on the model.

Here are extracts of code :

- Model user -->

  ```
  export default DS.Model.extend({
       name: DS.attr('string'),
       surname: DS.attr('string'),
       email: DS.attr('string'),
       photo: DS.attr('string'),
       institutions: DS.hasMany('institution', {async: true}),
       fullName: Ember.computed("surname", "name", function fullName(){
         return this.get('surname') + " " + this.get('name');
       }),
       avatar: Ember.computed("photo", function avatar(){
         return "/images/avatars/" + this.get('photo');
       })
  });
  ```

Institutions :

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  "shortname": DS.attr('string'),
  "photo": DS.attr('string'),
  "address": DS.attr('string'),
  "zipcode": DS.attr('string'),
  "city": DS.attr('string'),
  "type": DS.attr('string'),
  "dataset": DS.attr('string'),
  "website": DS.attr('string'),
  "phone" : DS.attr('string'),
  "rectorat": DS.attr('string'),
  "users": DS.hasMany('user', {async: true}),
  picture: Ember.computed("photo", function picture(){
    return "images/institutions/" + this.get('photo');
  })
});
```

And the JSON API returned by the server :

```
{
   "links": {
      "self": "users/"
   },
   "data": {
      "type": "user",
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
         "user_id": 1,
         "name": "User",
         "surname": "Beta",
         "email": "test@xxx.com",
         "photo": "user.jpg",
         "institutions": [
            2
         ]
      },
      "links": {
         "self": "users//1"
      },
      "relationships": {
         "institutions": [
            {
               "links": {
                  "self": "institutions/2"
               },
               "data": {
                  "type": "institutions",
                  "id": 2,
                  "attributes": {
                     "institution_id": 2,
                     "shortname": "Standford Maternelle",
                     "photo": "mrclpgnl.jpeg",
                     "address": "12 rue Riquet",
                     "zipcode": "75019",
                     "city": "Paris",
                     "type": "Lycée",
                     "dataset": "xjdfhdjhkfshfdsjkhfdskjhf",
                     "website": "http://standford.com",
                     "phone": "0478585527",
                     "rectorat": "666881548451354564",
                     "users": [
                        1
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "included": [
      {
         "type": "institutions",
         "id": 2,
         "attributes": {
            "institution_id": 2,
            "shortname": "Standford Maternelle",
            "photo": "mrclpgnl.jpeg",
            "address": "12 rue Riquet",
            "zipcode": "75019",
            "city": "Paris",
            "type": "Lycée",
            "dataset": "xjdfhdjhkfshfdsjkhfdskjhf",
            "website": "http://standford.com",
            "phone": "0478585527",
            "rectorat": "666881548451354564",
            "users": [
               1
            ]
         },
         "links": {
            "self": "institutions/2"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Do you have an idea about why don't I have a relationship properly and what do I have to do to have something like this :

```
{{#each user.institutions as |institution|}}
   {{institution.shortname}}
{{/each}}
```

Thanks a lot !! :D

Comment: I dont know, how your route and controller looks like. If `user` is the model you return in your route, you should try `{{#each model.institutions as |institution|}}`

Comment: That's what I do and model.institutions is empty (yes I didn't copied but it's not "user" but "model" but the idea stays the same). The model has the user and works properly (example model.surname) but model.institutions is not working :/

Comment: That works :) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try with this instead:

```
{
    "data": {
      "type": "users",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes":{ 
        "name": "User",
        "surname": "Beta",
        "email": "test@xxx.com",
        "photo": "user.jpg",
      },
      "relationships": {
        "institutions": {
          "links": {
            "self": "/users/1/relationships/institutions",
            "related": "/users/1/institutions"
          },
          "data": [{ "type": "institutions", "id": "1" }]
        }
      }
    },
    "included": [{
      "type": "institution",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "shortname": "Standford Maternelle",
        "photo": "mrclpgnl.jpeg",
        "address": "12 rue Riquet",
        "zipcode": "75019",
        "city": "Paris",
        "type": "Lycée",
        "dataset": "xjdfhdjhkfshfdsjkhfdskjhf",
        "website": "http://standford.com",
        "phone": "0478585527",
        "rectorat": "666881548451354564",
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/institutions/1"
      }
    }]

  }
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/sekuji/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks. That works, the object is recognized but when I try to parse it, I get the following error : 

Error: Adapter operation failed
    at new Error (native)

I don't have any adapter at the moment.

An idea ?

Comment: Could you show your actual code with a jsbin or an ember twiddle?

Comment: That finally works. It was because I was async and didn't implemented the user/1/institution yet. It's now ok. Thanks again :)

Comment: Would you mind approving my answer?
Btw you can also use this tool to test models and their expected JSON.
http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/